# Create Switch and add it to Layout

Tags: java, android

I have a Fragment

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/switchLayout">
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

and want to add switches to the LinearLayout as soon as the Fragment is loaded

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    LinearLayout switchLayout = (LinearLayout) rootview.findViewById(R.id.switchLayout);

    Switch new_switch = new Switch(getActivity());
    new_switch.setText("test");
    new_switch.setChecked(true);
    switchLayout.addView(new_switch);

    return rootview;
}
```

but when the Fragment gets loaded nothing happens, the LinearLayout is displayed but the switch doesn't appear and I don't get any error messages.

I already tried adding

```
new_switch.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
);
```

but it makes no difference

*note: this is my first question here, hopefully it's not too stupid ^^*

Comment: What is your goal?

Comment: i am not sure, but since you create the switch programmatically maybe you should use a drawable or something like that. Maybe the switch is in your layout after the infalte, it just doesn't has an icon so you can see it

Comment: @Opoo I want to create switches based on a config (the config determines the number of switches and their label)

Comment: how did you place fragment on layout? Are you using `FragmentManager` or inside activity layout you placed `<fragment />`?

Comment: @j2ko I'm using FragmentManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to perform the same what you are doing and it works.

Main activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in MainActivity.java:

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.containerFragment, 
                new MyFragment()).commit();
```

MyFragment and fragment layout is the same as you described.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Okay, thank you, I'm stupid.
The LinearLayout has to have the orientation **vertical** instead of **horizontal** otherwise only one switch is visible.
I'm accepting your answer because it helped me find the problem.